# Stuck in reboot loop

Tags: laptop, reboot

Help! I decided to try ubuntu18.04.1 out.  I did a full wipe.. and chose to install hardware updates which did secure boot password thing. My computer lagged during install but completed and now it is stuck doing an infinite reboot loop.   Acer 
logo flashes, some text flashes and then Acer flashes in a loop.

I installed elementary which I had before this and still have a loop.  It seems that USB boot works and nothing else..  cannot get to bios.  Is it bricked?  I think this was the 18.10 bug I read about.  I thought that was fixed.

Acer r 11 8gb ram 32 gb hd

I'm thinking will install win 10 to see if that can make an efi directory or something. I also have a USB windows.  I can try to flash the BIOS from there?

Am.i totally bricked?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a win usb disk and installed windows.  Then I installed elementary again (no more ubuntu after this install, thank you).
I think what happened was that I had deleted a partition that was necessary for the uefi booting procedure as part of the full wipe, or maybe the windows boot manager which was deleted for the very first time, even though I had a pure linux machine for 8 or so months..  Installing Windows put that back together for me and I could boot without a boot looping cycle.

Then, while installing eOS, instead of doing a full wipe (something I have never done on my machine before until the ubuntu install), I did a "something else" and reformatted the partition where windows was and made that root partition.  After that, I needed to use boot-repair to make my grub show up, which is often normal.  In retrospect, I think it would have been good to do boot repair first before anything else.  But I think that the full wipe deleted the partitions I needed.  Any comments are welcome.  The BIOS was fine which I suspected was the BIOS bug.